# If the class name is known as a string, is it possible to construct an instance of that class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, dynamic, actionscript

If the class name is known as a string, is it possible to construct an instance of that class? Example:

```
var className:String = "MyClass";
var obj:* = new getClass(className)();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
var className:String = "MyClass";
var obj:Object = new (getDefinitionByName(className) as Class)();
```

Comment: .. and not to forget to prepend the class name with the full package path.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You have to use `getDefinitionByName(name:String):Object`
Make shure that the class you are referencing is available in the swf file

```
 var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName("flash.display.Sprite") as Class;
 var instance:Object = new ClassReference();
```

Answer (score 2):

While the given answers are correct, this might not work if you are using application domains.

To take into account application domain, use the following method:

```
public static function forName(name:String, applicationDomain:ApplicationDomain = null):Class {
    applicationDomain ||= ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
    var result:Class;

    while (!applicationDomain.hasDefinition(name)) {
        if (applicationDomain.parentDomain) {
            applicationDomain = applicationDomain.parentDomain;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    try {
        result = applicationDomain.getDefinition(name) as Class;
    } catch (e:ReferenceError) {
        throw new ClassNotFoundError("A class with the name '" + name + "' could not be found.");
    }
    return result;
}

var myClass:Class = forName(className);
var instance:Object = new myClass();
```

This method and many other utilities are available in the [AS3Commons Lang](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-lang/index.html) library

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is!

```
var myClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;
var instance:Object = new myClass();
```